# Getting Http Status code number (200, 301, 404, etc.) from HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, .net, http, httpwebrequest

I am trying to get the HTTP status code number from the `HttpWebResponse` object returned from a `HttpWebRequest`.  I was hoping to get the actual numbers (200, 301,302, 404, etc.)  rather than the text description. ("Ok", "MovedPermanently", etc.)  Is the number buried in a property somewhere in the response object?  Any ideas other than creating a big switch function?  Thanks.

```
HttpWebRequest webRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest
                                           .Create("http://www.gooogle.com/");
webRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)webRequest.GetResponse();
//Returns "MovedPermanently", not 301 which is what I want.
Console.Write(response.StatusCode.ToString());
```

Comment: For the opposite action: httpResponse.HTTPStatusCode = (HttpStatusCode)Enum.ToObject(typeof(HttpStatusCode), 404))

Answer (score 463, accepted):

```
Console.Write((int)response.StatusCode);
```

[HttpStatusCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode.aspx) (the type of `response.StatusCode`) is an enumeration where the values of the members match the HTTP status codes, e.g.

```
public enum HttpStatusCode
{
    ...
    Moved = 301,
    OK = 200,
    Redirect = 302,
    ...
}
```

Comment: but in case of "connectfailure" exception of webexception i get response as null, in that case how can i get the httpstatus code

Comment: @rusty: If the connection failed and thus the request could not be sent and no response could be received, there won't be any http status code.

Comment: How get **HTTP Substatus** value ? For example, _404.13 Content Length Too Large_ Reference: http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits

Comment: Bonus: `bool success = ((int)response.StatusCode) >= 200 && ((int)response.StatusCode) < 300;`

Comment: @Alain Double bonus; bool success = response.IsSuccessStatusCode;

Comment: work in asp.net core: with big "R" >> @Response.StatusCode

Comment: Reason: response.ReasonPhrase

Answer (score 256):

You have to be careful, server responses in the range of 4xx and 5xx throw a WebException. You need to catch it, and then get status code from a WebException object:

```
try
{
    wResp = (HttpWebResponse)wReq.GetResponse();
    wRespStatusCode = wResp.StatusCode;
}
catch (WebException we)
{
    wRespStatusCode = ((HttpWebResponse)we.Response).StatusCode;
}
```

Comment: I'm glad you mentioned the 4xx and 5xx because I was having issues with a program not acting properly. I should point out though that the current .NET framework will notify you of any uncaught exceptions so this is also a no-brainer.

Comment: As a bonus, one used to be able to decorate a method with [DebuggerNonUserCode]  and the Debugger would not stop in that method when an exception is thrown.  In this manner [poorly designed exceptions](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2008/09/10/vexing-exceptions/#comment-85105) could be wrapped and ignored. But now a [registry setting is required](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/devops/2016/02/12/using-the-debuggernonusercode-attribute-in-visual-studio-2015)

Answer (score 26):

As per 'dtb' you need to use HttpStatusCode, but following 'zeldi' you need to be extra careful with code responses >= 400.

This has worked for me:

```
HttpWebResponse response = null;
HttpStatusCode statusCode;
try
{
    response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
}
catch (WebException we)
{
    response = (HttpWebResponse)we.Response;
}

statusCode = response.StatusCode;
Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
sResponse = reader.ReadToEnd();
Console.WriteLine(sResponse);
Console.WriteLine("Response Code: " + (int)statusCode + " - " + statusCode.ToString());
```

Comment: HttpWebResponse implements IDisposable so dealing with that can be tricky. You can use the following instead which allows you to declare "response" inside a using block: public HttpWebResponse GetSafeResponse(HttpWebRequest request) { try { return (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse(); } catch (WebException we) { return (HttpWebResponse)we.Response; } }

Answer (score 20):

Just coerce the `StatusCode` to `int`.

```
var statusNumber;
try {
   response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
   // This will have statii from 200 to 30x
   statusNumber = (int)response.StatusCode;
}
catch (WebException we) {
    // Statii 400 to 50x will be here
    statusNumber = (int)we.Response.StatusCode;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
//Response being your httpwebresponse
Dim str_StatusCode as String = CInt(Response.StatusCode)
Console.Writeline(str_StatusCode)
```

Comment: This is vb.net, the OP is using C#

Comment: ..and I am using vb.  Glad this answer was here.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i am handling such a situation.

```
//string details = ...
//...
catch (WebException ex)
{
    HttpStatusCode statusCode = ((HttpWebResponse)ex.Response).StatusCode;
    if (statusCode == HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized)
    {
        Reconnect();
        //...
    }
    else if (statusCode == HttpStatusCode.NotFound)
    {
        FileLogger.AppendToLog("[ERROR] Not Found: " + details);
    }
    else
    {
        FileLogger.AppendToLog("[ERROR] " + ex.Message + ": " + details);
    }
}
```