# What is the best way to validate a email domain?

Tags: c#, dns

In my application I validate a email domain like this:

```
public bool DomainValid(string domainName)
{
    try
    {
        IPHostEntry entry = Dns.GetHostEntry(domainName);
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The method is good, but not on every cases, like 'mpg.ro' is a valid email domain but it catches an Exception.

Can someone give me another idea of email domain validation in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From command prompt:

```
nslookup -type=mx <domain.name>
```

you can implement this inside C# too and read the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You could request the root of the domain, then parse the HTTP response? If it's 200, you're good to go

Comment: can you give me an example? Thanks

Comment: check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330856/getting-http-status-code-number-200-301-404-etc-from-httpwebrequest-and-ht

You'll definitely want the exception handling recommended there too.

Comment: yes but... HttpWebRequest expects a web page and 'mpg.ro' (for example) is just a domain, there is no web page www.mpg.ro, so it enters an exception there too..

Answer (score 2):

You could do a dns lookup on the [mx record](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record).  Here's an example at Code Project:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/dnslookupdotnet.aspx

I hope it will helps you ...

Comment: As I can see there you need a dns server address.. Is there a way that it can be done without any ip?