# In c#( .net) system.net.http, how to get the response.statuscode as an int? Not to use HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse

Tags: c#, system.net.httpwebrequest

```
        var hcHandler = new HttpClientHandler();
        //hcHandler.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        var hc = new HttpClient(hcHandler);
        hc.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 10.0; Windows NT 6.2; WOW64; Trident/6.0)");
        String url = "http://passport.cnblogs.com/login.aspx";
        var task = hc.GetAsync(new Uri(url));
        HttpResponseMessage response = task.Result;

        string statusCode = response.StatusCode.ToString();
```

I want to get the statusCode in integer, how can I do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Getting Http Status code number (200, 301, 404, etc.) from HttpWebRequest and HttpWebResponse](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1330856/getting-http-status-code-number-200-301-404-etc-from-httpwebrequest-and-ht)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`HttpResponseMessage.StatusCode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.statuscode(v=vs.118).aspx) is a [`HttpStatusCode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpresponsemessage.statuscode(v=vs.118).aspx) enum, whose underlying integer type is `int`, so you can just cast it:

```
int statusCode = (int)response.StatusCode;
```

Answer (score 3):

`HttpStatusCode` is declared as an enum sort of like:

```
enum HttpStatusCode
{
     NotFound = 404,
     ...
}
```

Which means you can do it simply by casting:

```
int status = (int)HttpStatusCode.NotFound;
```